# Regular Expression To Find C Style Comments

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to find C style headers in Java source files. At the present time I am experimenting with this with Python.

Here is my source code:

```
import re

text = """/*
       * Copyright blah blah blha blah 
       * blah blah blah blah 
       * 2008 blah blah blah @ org
       */"""

print
print "I guess the program printed the correct thing."

pattern = re.compile("^/.+/$")

print "-----------"
print pattern 

pos = 0
while True:
    match = pattern.search(text, pos)
    if not match:
        break
    s = match.start()
    e = match.end()
    print '   %2d : %2d = "%s"' % (s, e-1, text[s:e])
    pos = e
```

I am trying to write a simple expression that just looks for anything between a forward slash and another forward slash. I can make the regular expression more complicated later.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? I am using a forward slash the dot meta-character, the plus symbol for 1 or more things, and the dollar symbol for the end.

Comment: Could you please also provide the output of your program?

Comment: You're not looking for a header but for C-style comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735506/python-regex-reading-in-c-style-comments

Comment: Ah thank-you for the heads up. I was typing without thinking again. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should anchor (using '^' and '$') the match.

Secondly, I think the regex should be `r"/[^/]*/"` which matches a (portion of) a string that starts with a slash, followed by zero or more non-slash characters and then terminates with a slash.

To wit:

```
>>> import re                                                                                                                           
>>> text = """foo bar baz                                                                                                     
... /*                                                                                  
...        * Copyright blah blah blha blah                                                                                              
...        * blah blah blah blah                                                                                                        
...        * 2008 blah blah blah @ org                                                                                                  
...        */"""                                                                                                                          
>>> rx = re.compile(r"/[^/]*/", re.DOTALL)                                                                                              
>>> mo = rx.search(text)                                                                                                                
>>> text[mo.start(): mo.end()]                                                                                                          
'/*\n       * Copyright blah blah blha blah \n       * blah blah blah blah \n       * 2008 blah blah blah @ org\n       */'
```

Note that the comment does not start a the start of the string but that the regex finds it nicely.

Comment: Good point on the `^` & `$` anchors as this will stop working once he starts parsing actual files rather than the sample text.

Comment: I went with his answer because of the point on the regex anchors.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you need to specify the [`DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag because by default, the `.` character does not match newlines.

Try:

```
pattern = re.compile("^/.+/$", re.DOTALL)
```