# Get text between conventional comment syntax

Tags: javascript, regex

So if I wanted to grab the text between excluding the comment system:

```
/*this is a comment*/
//this is too
//and so is this...
This, however, isn't.
```

the output would be

```
This, however, isn't.
```

How can I do this with javascript? I was going to grab the regex of it, but I'm not sure what to do with the comments that end in whitespace...

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Maybe I've been unclear.

I have an array of the text above. I want to get rid of anything that isn't in the comments and I want to display the comments as they were. So:

```
/*This is a longggg
  comment that crosses several lines
  etc etc etc*/
this is plain text. i want to ignore this //however, this is another comment
/*one more comment here*/
```

This would be outputted as:

```
 /*This is a longggg
  comment that crosses several lines
  etc etc etc*/
 //however, this is another comment
 /*one more comment here*/
```

Comment: Comments are not read by any scripting or programming language they are just ignored when code is run. So you cannot read a a comment at all.

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow - I think he just wants to use Javascript as a parser, given the comment as a string.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Here's the [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735506/python-regex-reading-in-c-style-comments?lq=1) for it if you want a regex. It's quite complex, because it must exclude /\* ... \*/ within double-quotes, etc.

Comment: Rather than regexp, I would recommend either using a JS parser like Esprima, or some kind of minifier like uglify.

Comment: How do you want to handle `var x = 1 /* add */ + 2;`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this regex to match all comments in your code:

```
/(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)/igm
```

Then store your comments in a separate variable.
Then show that variable where you want to show all comments.

Comment: This regexp seems to be invalid syntax. For example, at the beginning you have `(/`, but `/` is not a valid character in a regexp unless escaped. I also doubt if this regexp will work with comment-like constructs in a string, such as `var s = "/* Hello */";`.

Comment: Please provide a link to the specific regexpal page for this regexp.

Comment: That shows the first forward slash with a red underline, and when I hover over it, it says "unescaped forward slash". When I type this regexp into the Chrome console, it reports a syntax error. It seems like regexpal is being "helpful" by treating the forward slashes as if they were escaped, but other environments will not be as forgiving.

Comment: This regexp fails on `/* foo bar // */`.

Comment: Can you give URL? It is working fine on /* foo bar // */

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this reliably using a regexp. You should use a minifer which strips comments (like uglify), or a JS parser (like esprima). Having said that, the following might work more or less:

```
/\/\*[^]*?\*\/|\/\/.*$/gm
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^              CAPTURE /* */ COMMENTS
              ^^^^^^^       CAPTURE // COMMENTS
```

Note the order. We need to look for the `/* */` style comments first, because otherwise we might pick up a `//` sequence inside the `/* */`.

Using `[^]` here to pick up any character, including newlines. Other people like to use `[\s\S]`.

However, this will not deal properly with things that look like comments inside of strings.