# How to capture between two characters in python using regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to get everything between `/*` and `*/`

I am using `re` library and following expression to get data

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\/\*)(.|\n)+?(?=\*\/)')
result = pattern.findall(query)
```

*query* - a string with data shown in the image (may contain line breaks, etc.)

my expression is not working correctly and I get this result

```
['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']
```

how can I get all content in between `/*` and `*/`?

[image]

Comment: If your file came from Windows it might have `\r` characters in it as well as `\n`

Comment: If you `open()` a file with Python, it'll use universal newlines of just `\n`!

Comment: Capturing content inside C-style comments [Python Regex reading in c style comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735506/python-regex-reading-in-c-style-comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `re.DOTALL` to make `.` match newlines
2. Don't escape forward slashes
3. Non-capturing syntax is: `(?:<expr>)`

```py
>>> txt = """
/*
name = foo
table = bar
*/ don't capture this
"""
>>> re.findall(r'(?:/\*)(.*?)(?:\*/)', txt, re.DOTALL)
['\nname: foo\ntable: bar\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had this issue I resolved it by just removing new lines from string. For your example:

```
query.replace('\n', '')
```